# Replace all values in a flat array with 0

Tags: php, arrays, replace, default-value, fill

Is there any ***default function*** to clear **only the values** of an array?

For example:

```
$array = [
    10,
    3,
    3,
    34,
    56,
    12
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$array = array_combine(array_keys($array), array_fill(0, count($array), 0));
```

Alternative:

```
$array = array_map(create_function('', 'return 0;'), $array);
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your original question: No, there isn't any *default* PHP function for this. However, you can try some combination of other functions as other guys described. However, I find following piece of code more readable:

```
$numbers = Array( "a" => "1", "b" => 2, "c" => 3 );

foreach ( $numbers as &$number ) {
    $number = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array_fill(0, count($array), 0);
```

This creates an array of the original one's size filled with zeroes.

Comment: Although the OP didn't say so, I'm assuming the keys might not be continuously numeric. This solution would destroy the keys.

Comment: The code above works for your example (non-associative array). If you want to preserve keys, deceze's solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map()` to overwrite all values with `0`. This approach preserves the original keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/V6H1H))

```
$zeros = array_map(fn() => 0, $array);

var_export($zeros);
```